# npm install reactjs app npm ERR! code E404

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I am new to reactjs, and I am trying to create a reactjs app, and I follow the steps on react web, and it shows error. My node version is v8.11.1.npx version is 9.7.1.

btw I can create the app with `npx create-react-app`, but when fail with npm.

```
MacBook-teddy$ npm install -g create-react-app 
create-react-app amber_Web 
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found: amber_Web@latest

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/teddy/.npm/_logs/2018-06-07T02_08_37_384Z-debug.log
```

And this is the log file:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/usr/local/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   '-g',
1 verbose cli   'create-react-app',
1 verbose cli   'create-react-app',
1 verbose cli   'amber_Web' ]
2 info using npm@5.6.0
3 info using node@v8.11.1
4 verbose npm-session 452b1b32f613b960
5 silly install loadCurrentTree
6 silly install readGlobalPackageData
7 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/create-react-app 32ms (from cache)
8 silly pacote tag manifest for create-react-app@latest fetched in 52ms
9 http fetch GET 404 https://registry.npmjs.org/amber_Web 1545ms
10 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for amber_Web@latest 404 Not Found: amber_Web@latest
11 verbose stack Error: 404 Not Found: amber_Web@latest
11 verbose stack     at fetch.then.res (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/pacote/lib/fetchers/registry/fetch.js:42:19)
11 verbose stack     at tryCatcher (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
11 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:512:31)
11 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromise (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:569:18)
11 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromise0 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:614:10)
11 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromises (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:693:18)
11 verbose stack     at Async._drainQueue (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:133:16)
11 verbose stack     at Async._drainQueues (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:143:10)
11 verbose stack     at Immediate.Async.drainQueues (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:17:14)
11 verbose stack     at runCallback (timers.js:794:20)
11 verbose stack     at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:752:5)
11 verbose stack     at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:729:5)
12 verbose cwd /Users/teddy/Desktop
13 verbose Darwin 17.5.0
14 verbose argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "create-react-app" "create-react-app" "amber_Web"
15 verbose node v8.11.1
16 verbose npm  v5.6.0
17 error code E404
18 error 404 Not Found: amber_Web@latest
19 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you tried to run create-react-app while installing it.

Run `npm install -g create-react-app` although this should already be installed.

Then run `create-react-app amber-web`

---

**EDIT:**

The reason this error out was because you put `npm install -g create-react-app 
create-react-app amber_Web` all in one command telling npm to install the create-react-app package twice and the amber_Web package but that package doesn't exist hence the 404 error.
  *  name can no longer contain capital letters

Answer (score 1):

The error is because npm follows the application naming conventions, according to which it is not allowed to use upper case letters in the application names also.

Kindly try using `create-react-app amber_web`

To learn more kindly visit : [npmjs docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json)

Answer (score 1):

try:
**npm doctor**

**npm ping**

*"npm doctor runs a set of checks to ensure that your npm installation has what it needs to manage your JavaScript packages."*

Answer (score 1):

I think there could be problem in both cash and aslo react installation, so you should try:

```
npm cache clean --force
```

Then

```
npm install -g create-react-app
```

After that see your installation right or not by this

```
create-react-app --version
```

If it works then everything is ok now, but if not then you should try to uninstall node.js and try to search all it's caching folder delete them and install as frash node.js then insall react js.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
npm cache clean --force
```

and then

```
create-react-app your_app_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing helped me except

```
npm install -g webpack
```

npm -g list

```
├── create-react-app@5.0.1   
└── webpack@5.73.0
```

Answer (score -1):

Just set the registry as-
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org

And then run
npm install -g create-react-app

create the project
npx create-react-app your_app_name

Comment: I don't follow how this is different from the accepted answer, can you please provide additional details explaining that?